# Break, Continue in ExtJs

Tags: loops, extjs, panel, break, extjs5

I am using **nested loop** in ExtJs application. I want to use break, continue in below code. I know we can use return false to break from loop but when doesn't work properly.

Suppose first (outer) loop will run from 1 to 10 and second(inner) loop will run from 1 to 5. Now if condition is true (1==1) then it should be added item (checkbox) in panel only **one time.**. After adding item it should be break and outer loop will start continue.

Note - Everytime there is different panel will be created (According to my complete application code), so if condition will be true then every panel has only one checkbox.

**Let me know, if anything is not clear.**

My code is not working in fiddler. I don't know why. According to below code and my understanding, two checkbox should be created on button click.

Process should be run -

1. 1==1 will be true or if condition is satisfied after that inner loop will be stopped.
2. 2==2 will be true and inner loop will be stopped.

   ```
      Ext.onReady(function () {
      var window = new Ext.Window({
       id: 'grdWindow',
       width: 400,
       title: 'Grid Samples',
           items: [
               {
                   xtype: 'button',
                   text: 'testing',
                   handler: function () {

                       var obj1 = [
                           { a: 1},
                           { a: 2},
                           { a: 3},
                           { a: 4}
                       ];

                       var obj2 = [
                           { a: 1 },
                           { a: 2 }
                       ];

                       var panel = Ext.getCmp('pnlTesting');
                       Ext.each(obj1, function (ob1) {
                           Ext.each(obj2, function (ob2) {
                               if (ob1.a == ob2.a) {
                                   panel.add({
                                       items:[
                                           {
                                               xtype: 'checkbox',
                                           }
                                           ]
                                   });
                               }
                           });
                           return false;
                       });
                   }
               },
               {
                   xtype: 'panel',
                   id: 'pnlTesting',
                   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
               }   
           ]
       }).show();
   });
   ```

Comment: So what does not work properly when using `return false`?

Comment: Outer loop doesn't start, when I use return false after completing inner loop. It gives syntax error if I use return false before completing inner loop.

Comment: Show your code with `return false` or better a fiddle. There should not be any issues with returning `false`.

Comment: @DrakeEnterpriseSystems - I have added code on my question. It's not working properly in fiddler, don't why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the *outer* loop right after handling the first item of `obj1`. Item `{a: 2}` never gets checked against any `obj2` item.

Instead, you should be breaking the *inner* loop, and only when checkbox is added:

```
Ext.each(obj1, function (ob1) {
    Ext.each(obj2, function (ob2) {
        if (ob1.a == ob2.a) {
            container.add({
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'checkbox',
                    }
                ]
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

See fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sgb

Comment: Yes, I got it.. It was minor mistake by me.Thanks